# What does texture resolve mean?

Tags: texture, image-processing, sampling

In the context of render targets or textures, what does "resolve" mean?
For example: To resolve a color texture.

From my understanding, it seems to mean, "copy but process/convert at the same time", but I can't seem to find a good definition for it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about other contexts, but for DirectX resolving a texture means blending multi-sampled texture into a non-multisampled one. For simple scenarios this is usually done automatically by the output merger, but is often needed to be done explicitly (e.g. [ResolveSubresource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-resolvesubresource)) when using multi-sampled render target as an input for a next render pass (e.g. post-processing). Reasons being both performance and lower complexity of the following pass shaders.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some example usage from graphics papers might be helpful - it basically refers to computing a 'pixel' value potentially from multiple fragments...

**RealityEngine Graphics  (Akeley. 1993)**

> Thus the image is complete as soon as the last primitive
>   has been rendered; there is no need for a final framebuffer operation
>   to *resolve* the multiple color samples at each pixel location to a
>   single displayable color.

**Hardware Accelerated Rendering Of Antialiasing Using A Modified A-buffer Algorithm. (Winner et al, 1997)**

> Pixels which are completely covered by opaque objects are *resolved*
>   in a single pass.

or

> Otherwise multiple passes are required to *resolve* the final color
>   for each pixel in the scene.

**A Directionally Adaptive Edge Anti-Aliasing Filter. (Iourcha et al, 2009)**

> Downsampling is performed by a *resolve*, which is the aggregation of the samples with filtering.